# how to render my form into the index page ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a displaying table grid in my `index` page. I have a `new` button in the same page. When i click the `new` button, the `form` should appear in the same `index` page at the top of the table grid. How can i do that? i am new to ROR. So please help me in detail.

Here is my index page.

```
<div id="new_survey_link">
Create a
<%= link_to 'New', new_enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref_path %>
</div>

<table class="gridView">
  <tr class="gridViewHeader">
  <th>Section</th>
  <th>Questions</th>
  <th>Answer</th>
  <th>Element</th>
  <th>Sub Element</th>
  <th>Material</th>
  <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

  <% if @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xrefs.empty? %>
    <td class="empty_data" colspan="7">No Energy/Survey Cross references are currently exist.</td>
  <% else %>
  <% @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xrefs.each do |survey| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('gridViewclickableRowDialog', 'gridViewAltclickableRowDialog') %>">
    <td><%= survey.Section %></td>
    <td><%= survey.enr_rds_question_2009.question_text %></td>
    <td><%= survey.Answer_No %></td>
    <td><%= survey.element.Element %></td>
    <td><%= survey.sub_element.Sub_Element %></td>
    <td><%= survey.renew_schedule.Material %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', '#', :remote => true, class: "create-user" %> | 
      <%= link_to 'Delete', survey, method: :delete,
                                 confirm: "Are you sure?" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the form already in the page and hide it with style="display:none";
Then bind the click event of the "new" link to a javascript that toggles the visibility. like with jQuery you can have onclick="$('#new_survey_link a').toggle();"

Comment: my form div id is `#xref_form`. my link id is `newlink`. i hide through the css. But I dont know how to write a jquery for this id's.

Comment: jQuery uses css selectors, thus if your link has the attribute id="newlink", then you can access the, link like this
$("#newlink")
Further to attach an event listener to the link you can write
$("#newlink").click( function(eventObject){/*code goes here*/} )

Comment: am new to jquery as well.... so cant understand very well... sorry. can u explain in detail please?

Comment: It's quite simle to learn. I suggest you check out some tutorials first, like http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working. Is it possible to close the div with the cancel button instead of toggle?

Comment: use .show() and .hide() jquery built-in functions to display or hide html elements